# How to edit screens and and move backwards in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

So I'm working on an app that has a class object created in the first screen and as you move forward within the screens, the members of that class are given data. In the final screen, there's an option to edit whatever data that has been selected within the screens. Basically, let's say I have 5 screens and if I click on edit on the fifth screen, it should take me to screen 2 where I initially entered that data earlier, make changes and navigate back to screen 5 when I'm done. Is it possible to use Navigator.pop() and return the updated class object??

Comment: What I understand is that you want to pass data while going backwards, am I right?

Comment: Yes. But when I navigate to the second screen, instead of calling it again, I want to go the state that it already was in. Like say there's a selection of data in screen 2, and I select option 2. When I'm in the fifth screen and I click edit, option 2 must still be selected in the second screen when it is called again from the fifth screen